# Another @tx:annotation-driven causing autowired to fail for Junit Test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

using Spring 3+, Hibernate 4, Junit 4.8 I am getting the following **could not autowire field** msg

```
Running com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [test-springContext.xml]
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:27 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:27 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@121dcac: startup date [Sun Dec 22 18:30:27 GMT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:27 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [file:C:/Users/xxx/yyyy/mySVNWorkSpace/TwitterApiDemo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/database/database.properties]
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e86e8a: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,userDAOHibernate,propertiesConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:28 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:28 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:29 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:29 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.1.Final}
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:29 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:30 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:30 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@a6a2c3] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Dec 22, 2013 6:30:30 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a54967] to prepare test instance [com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest@762be3]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest.userDAOHibernate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:379)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest.userDAOHibernate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 34 more

Dec 22, 2013 6:30:30 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a54967] to prepare test instance [com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest@70a141]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest.userDAOHibernate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:379)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest.userDAOHibernate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 34 more

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.04 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  testDAOAutowire(com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest): Error creating bean with name 'com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest.userDAOHibernate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  testFindAll(com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest): Error creating bean with name 'com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest.userDAOHibernate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

my **test-springContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd           

">
     <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO"/>


    <!-- define place holder as a bean -->
    <bean id="propertiesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">        
            <list>
                <value>file:C:/Users/xxx/yyyy/mySVNWorkSpace/TwitterApiDemo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/database/database.properties</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- declare datasource that has pooled connection capabilities  -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>    
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>    
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>    
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>    

    </bean>

    <!-- annotation-based configuration  -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <!-- declare datasource that has pooled connection capabilities  -->
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>                        
        </property> <!-- already defined in dataSourcecontet refernce it here -->

      <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
          <value>com.twitter.apidemo.domain.User</value>        
        </list>
      </property>        

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate transaction manager -->

    **<tx:annotation-driven></tx:annotation-driven>**  
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

UserDAOHibernateTest

```
public class UserDAOHibernateTest extends DomainAwareBase {
     public UserDAOHibernateTest() {     
     }                 
   @Autowired(required = true)
    private UserDAOHibernate userDAOHibernate;


    @Test 
    public void testDAOAutowire(){
        assertNotNull(userDAOHibernate);   
    }
    @Test 
    public void testFindAll(){        
     List<User> appUsers  = userDAOHibernate.findAll();
    userDAOHibernate.flush();
     assert(appUsers.size() ==2);
    }   
}
```

DomainAwareBase is an abstract class contains the annotations

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:test-springContext.xml"
```

UserDAOHibernateTest is used to test **UserDAOHibernate** implementation

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserDAOHibernate extends GenericDAOHibernate<User,Long > implements UserDAO { 
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return super.findAll(); 
    }
}
```

the domain class **User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AppUser")
public class User implements Serializable {

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "int(10)", name = "AppUserId", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    getters/setters and other fields not shown
```

the code works fine when I comment out **tx:annotationdriven** otherwise I get the BeanCreationError. What am I doing wrong. Help very much appreciated.

**Edit** The stack trace from proxy-target-class="true"

```
Running com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest
Dec 22, 2013 8:07:05 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [test-springContext.xml]
Dec 22, 2013 8:07:05 PM 
Dec 22, 2013 8:07:06 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [file:C:/Users/yyyyy/mySVNWorkSpace/TwitterApiDemo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/database/database.properties]
Dec 22, 2013 8:07:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Dec 22, 2013 8:07:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in     Dec 22, 2013 8:07:10 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@311578] to prepare test instance [com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest@78adb2]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOHibernate' defined in file [C:\Users\yyyy\mySVNWorkSpace\TwitterApiDemo\target\classes\com\twitter\apidemo\persistence\hibernateDAO\UserDAOHibernate.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is     Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate]: Common causes of this     Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.ClassCastException-->java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.GenericDAOHibernate.<init>(GenericDAOHibernate.java:31)
    at com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate.<init>(UserDAOHibernate.java:14)
    at com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f06044b3.<init>(<generated>)
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [test-springContext.xml]
Dec 22, 2013 8:07:10 PM loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [file:C:/Users//mySVNWorkSpace/TwitterApiDemo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/database/database.properties]
Dec 22, 2013 8:07:10 PM     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOHibernate' defined in file [C:\Users\yyy\mySVNWorkSpace\TwitterApiDemo\target\classes\com\twitter\apidemo\persistence\hibernateDAO\UserDAOHibernate.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.twitter.apidemo.persistence.hibernateDAO.UserDAOHibernate]:     Tests in error: 
  testFindAll(com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testDAOAutowire(com.twitter.apidemo.test.integration.UserDAOHibernateTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Edit **GenericDAOHibernate**

```
public abstract class GenericDAOHibernate<T,ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO<T, ID>{   
    private Class<T> persistentClass;
    private Session session;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public GenericDAOHibernate() {// need to know what is the class of the entity to persist find by reflection        
        this.persistentClass= (Class<T>)( (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass() ).getActualTypeArguments()[0];                
    }
it has get/set session methods
```

Comment: try `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` ?

Comment: I had it before and it did not work.

Comment: @iNan The default `TransactionManager` bean is `transactionManager`.

Comment: Try adding `proxy-target-class="true"` to your `<tx:annotation-driven>` element. I'll explain why if it works. You'll need CGLIB on your classpath.

Comment: just added CGlib ver 3 to the POM, added proxy-target-class="true" to the test-SpringContext rerun the test I am getting failed to load applicationContext

Comment: Edit that exception into your question.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis do you mean the last error stack trace?

Comment: Yes, please add it. We can remove it later if it doesn't relate.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis sorry for the delay I could not fit the trace within max char rule. I have chopped alot of the trace and left the necessary INFO and added the trace to the original post

Comment: Please post your `GenericDAOHibernate` class constructor.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis See the edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go on the track on proposing change this

```
public GenericDAOHibernate() {
    this.persistentClass= (Class<T>)( (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass() ).getActualTypeArguments()[0];                
}
```

which won't work because `getClass()` returns the Proxy class that CGLIB is creating. to

```
public GenericDAOHibernate() {
    this.persistentClass = getDaoClass();           
}
```

where `getDaoClass()` would be implemented in the sub classes such as

```
public Class<User> /* Class<T> in the parent class */ getDaoClass() {
    return User.class;
}
```

I'll add the rest of the explanation if this works.

Comment: Sotirios that worked a treat, fantastic, please could you provide the explanation

Comment: @RaadMohammed I will. But it'll have to wait until tomorrow, I'm leaving the house now. If you want to look into the original root cause, check out the difference between JDK proxies and CGLIB proxies when applied to Spring injection.

Comment: No problem and thanks very much. I will vote up when I get 15 reputations